# MySQL String Manipulations: Change the 5th character, counting from the end

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to change the 5th character in a column from last.

For example,

- path/of/images/1232323_`m`.jpg

to

- path/of/images/1232323_`b`.jpg

How to do that using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
update your_table
set col = replace(col, 'm.jpg', 'b.jpg')
```

Comment: Happens to be correct when the last 5 characters are m.jpg, but the question was more generic: "how to change the 5th character, counting from the end of a string"

Comment: I agree with @Konerak. Not the exact one. but helped me.

Answer (score 4):

```
update your_table
 set col = concat(substring(col, 1, length(col) -5), 'b', substring(col, -4))
where length(col) > 5  --if you really need.
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31774/2

Comment: this will replace every m with b -> path/of/ibages

Comment: Yeah, but you change EVERY m in the string. Your command would be: `set col = replace(col,'m','b')` so images->ibages.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus what about col shorter than 5 chars?

Comment: @pQd well, if it's about file names, it will be hard... But theorically yes. By the way the third part of your concat could be simplified ;)

Answer (score 1):

check

```
select col, if(length(col)<5,col,concat(substr(col,1,length(col)-5),'X',substr(col,length(col)-3,5))) from table;
```

and based on it run update:

```
update table set col=concat(substr(col,1,length(col)-5),'X',substr(col,length(col)-3,5)) where length(col)>5;
```

live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbc21/2/0

Comment: This is the (first/only) answer going in the right direction ('every char but the last five' + new char + 'last four chars'), but unfortunately this is a SELECT, not an UPDATE. Care to make this the actual correct answer?

Comment: Correct! Have [a free SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbc21/2/0) to prove your solution works ;-)